# "setting a property that has only a getter"- javascript error with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Up until recently, I had been using Safari 4 for testing and debugging my current jQuery Plugin.  I tried my code out in Firefox and it started to complain about something within the JQuery-Framework: "setting a property that has only a getter".
I tried to find out which line causes Firefox to complain and found that this happens somewhere here**

```
$.fn.util.create_$dom = function(opt) {
    var $dom = {};
    $.each(opt.dom,function(name,val){
        console.log(name);
        var $elm = $('<div>');
        $.each(opt.dom[name],function(_name,_val){
            if(_name == 'tagName') $elm = $('<'+_val+'/>');
        });
                    console.log(name+': ok');
        $.each(opt.dom[name],function(_name,_val){             **here       
            switch(_name){                                     **here
                case 'className': $elm.addClass(_val);         **here
                default: $elm.attr(_name, _val);               **here
            }                                                  **here
        });
        $dom[name] = $elm;
        console.log(name+': ok');
    });
    return $dom;
};
```

options.dom looks like this:

```
    dom:{
        wrapper:{className:'wrapper'},
        inner:{tagName:'p',className:'test',test:'bla'}
    },
```

Comment: guess ppl are smarter in the mornings... kinda it was the case with me after drinking a strong coffee and taking a deep breath.

redsquare was totally right about the problem of course, and i got a similar solution:

i just added:

case 'tagName': break;

in order to avoid this problem, and firefox loves me for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your trying to set the tagName of an element with this line

```
$elm.attr(_name, _val);
```

This of course is not possible as it is read only.

Comment: ..but it seemed to be possible in safari would you say there is a workaround for firefox?

Comment: safari probably just swallows the exception. You can always wrap it in a try catch but why not have another case statement for tagName that does not set the tagName since you have already created the appropriate element.

Comment: why not just delete the first each and move the condition you have inside it to be a case statement. You will have to ensure that tagName is the first item in the array however. I would maybe look at the structure of your object however to avoid the possibility of this

Comment: yeah kinda this is why i added this first each loop, i wanted to stay flexible within the object notation

Comment: Anyway. Mark it up:) as it answers the Q.

Comment: mmh, not yet :)... because it didn't work for me so far, i tried to fix it in this way but firefox is still in a bad mood

Comment: Well, I identified where the issue was and why it was happening. The remit was not to provide a whole working solution;)

Comment: ok sir, thx for your quick response anyway, and you kinda helped me of course, but i want to wait at least 1-2 days for other responses

Answer (score 3):

```
case 'tagName': break;
```

... is the solution, but in order to thank redsquare for the hint i marked him up.